# Create a table from Select Bigquery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

Hi i can create a table from an old table using sql in MSSQL or Oracle like this:

```
Select * into new_table  from  old_table;
```

Is it possible to do it in BigQuery? I got an error when typing this in the  console: "Error: Encountered " "INTO" "INTO "" at line 2, column 1. Was expecting:  ".

I have a Select with an inline User Defined Function. I like to take the output of this select and store it in a separate table.

Comment: it is a good practice (and you can definitelly do it) to answer your own question if you feel you have good one (as it looks like in this case). overall common sense rule is to keep answer separatelly from question

Comment: yes you are right :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `into`, but you can click on "show options" and select a table there.

Comment: Thx dude, is there a way doing this via the .net api?

Comment: Yes. I am not familiar with the .net api, but this is possible by setting the DestinationTable property. Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1JobConfigurationQuery.html#ab086707c20c7703b9c0a3d113fc71aa7

Answer (score 2):

For those who is looking for a solution in C# over the .NET Client API (Thx oulenz for the hint):

```
   public void ExecQueryIntoTable(string projectId, string dataSetId, string destinationTable, string query)
    {
        try
        {
            JobsResource jobResource = bigqueryService.Jobs;
            Job theJob = new Job();
            theJob.Configuration = new JobConfiguration()
            {
                Query = new JobConfigurationQuery()
                {
                    AllowLargeResults = true,
                    CreateDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                    DefaultDataset = new DatasetReference() { ProjectId = projectId, DatasetId = dataSetId},
                    MaximumBillingTier = 100,
                    DestinationTable = new TableReference() { ProjectId = projectId, DatasetId = dataSetId, TableId = destinationTable },
                    Query = query
                }
            };

            var result = jobResource.Insert(theJob, projectId).Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message + ", StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know whether the above is correct.
When using large tables, the above jobresource.Insert ... may be not finished (it run asynchronously, so I need to check the state, or run it synchronously) - How can I do that?